# Copy input xml to output and remove unwanted namespace out of it

Tags: xml, soap, xslt-2.0, ibm-datapower

I have below XMl:

```
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2"
xmlns:m0="http:test/201/3"
xmlns:ns0="http:test/201/4"
xmlns:ns2="http:test/201/5"
xmlns:ns1="http:test/201/6"
xmlns:ns3="http:test/201/7"
xmlns:ns6="http:test/201/8"
xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Header>
<ns0:ResponseHeader>
<ns:Env>Dev</ns:Env>
<ns:Version>1</ns:Version>
<ns:Server></ns:Server>
<ns:Name>NAME</ns:Name>
</ns0:ResponseHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<ns2:ResponseData>
<ns2:Employee >
<ns2:MessageList xsi:type="ns3:Info">
<ns2:Message>
<ns4:Type>new</ns4:Type>
<ns4:Code>2</ns4:Code>
<ns4:Source>Emp</ns4:Source>
<ns4:Description>new hire</ns4:Description>
</ns2:Message>
</ns2:MessageList>
<ns2:MessageList xsi:type="ns3:Info">
<ns2:Message>
<ns4:Type>new</ns4:Type>
<ns4:Code>1</ns4:Code>
<ns4:Source>contract</ns4:Source>
<ns4:Description>new hire</ns4:Description>
</ns2:Message>
</ns2:MessageList>
</ns2:Employee>
</ns2:ResponseData>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My Requirement is, copy complete input xml elements and attributes to output xml include all namespaces except xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/".
So Desire Output is:

My Requirement is, copy complete input xml elements and attributes to output xml include all namespaces except xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/".
So Desire Output is:

```
<Envelope
xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2"
xmlns:m0="http:test/201/3"
xmlns:ns0="http:test/201/4"
xmlns:ns2="http:test/201/5"
xmlns:ns1="http:test/201/6"
xmlns:ns3="http:test/201/7"
xmlns:ns6="http:test/201/8"
xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
<ns0:ResponseHeader>
<ns:Env>Dev</ns:Env>
<ns:Version>1</ns:Version>
<ns:Server></ns:Server>
<ns:Name>NAME</ns:Name>
</ns0:ResponseHeader>
</Header>
<Body>
<ns2:ResponseData>
<ns2:Employee >
<ns2:MessageList xsi:type="ns3:Info">
<ns2:Message>
<ns4:Type>new</ns4:Type>
<ns4:Code>2</ns4:Code>
<ns4:Source>Emp</ns4:Source>
<ns4:Description>new hire</ns4:Description>
</ns2:Message>
</ns2:MessageList>
<ns2:MessageList xsi:type="ns3:Info">
<ns2:Message>
<ns4:Type>new</ns4:Type>
<ns4:Code>1</ns4:Code>
<ns4:Source>contract</ns4:Source>
<ns4:Description>new hire</ns4:Description>
</ns2:Message>
</ns2:MessageList>
</ns2:Employee>
</ns2:ResponseData>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: Your output contains `soap:Envelope` so it needs to have some `xmlns:soap="..."` declaration.

Comment: My bad. soap prefix elements will be replaced by local names. so thats why it is not required. so final desire output is.

Comment: Please edit your question's code samples to reflect the desired output. It seems you did also already post a similar question with an accepted solution, is this question different? If so, why?

Comment: Previous one, Doesnot have attributes. that is only different.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform all `soap:foo` elements to `foo` elements in no namespace and remove the `soap` namespace then using

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs soap"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="soap:*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(. = namespace-uri(current()))]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

should suffice, assuming your root element is in the soap namespace and has all the namespace declarations in scope.

When I apply above XSLT to the input sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2"
    xmlns:m0="http:test/201/3"
    xmlns:ns0="http:test/201/4"
    xmlns:ns2="http:test/201/5"
    xmlns:ns1="http:test/201/6"
    xmlns:ns3="http:test/201/7"
    xmlns:ns6="http:test/201/8"
    xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Header>
        <ns0:ResponseHeader>
            <ns:Env>Dev</ns:Env>
            <ns:Version>1</ns:Version>
            <ns:Server></ns:Server>
            <ns:Name>NAME</ns:Name>
        </ns0:ResponseHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:ResponseData>
            <ns2:Employee >
                <ns2:MessageList xsi:type="ns3:Info">
                    <ns2:Message>
                        <ns4:Type>new</ns4:Type>
                        <ns4:Code>2</ns4:Code>
                        <ns4:Source>Emp</ns4:Source>
                        <ns4:Description>new hire</ns4:Description>
                    </ns2:Message>
                </ns2:MessageList>
                <ns2:MessageList xsi:type="ns3:Info">
                    <ns2:Message>
                        <ns4:Type>new</ns4:Type>
                        <ns4:Code>1</ns4:Code>
                        <ns4:Source>contract</ns4:Source>
                        <ns4:Description>new hire</ns4:Description>
                    </ns2:Message>
                </ns2:MessageList>
            </ns2:Employee>
        </ns2:ResponseData>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

in your post then Saxon 9.6 creates the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Envelope xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2" xmlns:m0="http:test/201/3" xmlns:ns0="http:test/201/4" xmlns:ns2="http:test/201/5" xmlns:ns1="http:test/201/6" xmlns:ns3="http:test/201/7" xmlns:ns6="http:test/201/8" xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <ns0:ResponseHeader>
            <ns:Env>Dev</ns:Env>
            <ns:Version>1</ns:Version>
            <ns:Server/>
            <ns:Name>NAME</ns:Name>
        </ns0:ResponseHeader>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <ns2:ResponseData>
            <ns2:Employee>
                <ns2:MessageList xsi:type="ns3:Info">
                    <ns2:Message>
                        <ns4:Type>new</ns4:Type>
                        <ns4:Code>2</ns4:Code>
                        <ns4:Source>Emp</ns4:Source>
                        <ns4:Description>new hire</ns4:Description>
                    </ns2:Message>
                </ns2:MessageList>
                <ns2:MessageList xsi:type="ns3:Info">
                    <ns2:Message>
                        <ns4:Type>new</ns4:Type>
                        <ns4:Code>1</ns4:Code>
                        <ns4:Source>contract</ns4:Source>
                        <ns4:Description>new hire</ns4:Description>
                    </ns2:Message>
                </ns2:MessageList>
            </ns2:Employee>
        </ns2:ResponseData>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: above xslt is working well expect there is soap namespace attribute copying child element of soap prefix element. <Header>
<ns0:ResponseHeader xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <Body>
<ns2:ResponseData xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>

Comment: I have tested the code against the input sample you posted and have included the result in the answer, there is no `xmlns:soap` declaration so you will have to tell us in detail which XSLT processor you used if you really still have the problem.

Comment: I am using in datapower aboue xslt code which you posted.

Comment: I am not familiar with datapower and whether it fully implements XSLT 2.0 with for instance `xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no"`. You might want to add a tag for datapower to see whether others can help.

Comment: @Mike, as long as there is nothing soap:.. in your result xml then just the namespace declaration `xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` should not do any harm. Does datapower show anyhing in log/debug log that would indicate that it would not accept (all of/part of) the xslt version 2 stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

DataPower only implements XSLT 1.0, not 2.0.

You can control your namespaces through Copy:

```
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:element name="ns:Element" namespace="http://www.xml.com/ns">
</xsl:copy>
```